# c# Making no difference between comma and dot in doubles/for console

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and C# and i can't find any solution.

I've made a small calculator just to try out some basics (i know it's not a clean code)

So because i've german settings and utf-8 (i think) i must write 1,5 instead of 1.5

In my calculator it gives no error if i type in 1.5 it makes 15

I want to be able using both methods so i can type in 1.5 or 1,5

Maybe somebody can explain it for dummies ^^

Sry for the colors, but thats my next question. Is there any way i can change color only for one line and using standard one in next line without set it to white like me?

Thanks for any help and a big sorry for my english - following shows my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            double zahl1, zahl2, ergebnis = 0;
            string operand;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Zahl1:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("1. Zahl:");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                string eingabe = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    zahl1 = double.Parse(eingabe);
                }

                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Eingabe ungültig");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    goto Zahl1;
                }

                Operand:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;            
                Console.WriteLine("Operand wählen [ ( + ), ( - ), ( / oder : ), ( * oder x ) ]");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                operand = Console.ReadLine();
                if(operand == "+" || operand == "-" || operand == "X" || operand == "x" || operand == "*" || operand == "/" || operand == ":")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Kein gültiger Operand");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    goto Operand;
                }

                Zahl2:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("2. Zahl:");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                string eingabe2 = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    zahl2 = double.Parse(eingabe2);
                }

                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Eingabe ungültig");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    goto Zahl2;
                }



                if (operand == "+")
                {
                    ergebnis = zahl1 + zahl2;
                }

                else if (operand == "-")
                {
                    ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;
                }

                else if (operand == "/" || operand == ":")
                {
                    ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2;
                }

                else if (operand == "*" || operand.ToUpper() == "X")
                {
                    ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;
                }

                // Sollte nie erreicht werden
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Kein gültiger Operand - Ergebnis = 0 ¯\\_(-.-)_/¯");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Console.WriteLine("Ergebnis: " + ergebnis);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("Neue Rechnung? (y || j) Oder Beenden? (beliebige Taste außer y und j)");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

                ConsoleKeyInfo eingabekey = Console.ReadKey();

                if (eingabekey.Key == ConsoleKey.Y || eingabekey.Key == ConsoleKey.J)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to automatically detect which format the user is trying to use. You will have to have a toggle to switch between the two modes.

Comment: 1.5 can either mean 1.5 or 15 depending on the locale. You have to use one locale to parse the correct value and let user select which locale he wants if you want to support multiple.

Comment: @gp And the other example is 1,001. Does that mean one-thousand-and-one or one-point-zero-zero-one? Depends on the locale.

Comment: yes... e.g. dot is thousand separator and comma is decimal in de-DE locale.
`(123456.789).toLocaleString('de-DE')` => "`123.456,789`"

Comment: thanks all for this input, i've got it working to accept both as a comma now